# System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType has no key defined

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am trying to create an sdf with Code-First, however I am getting an error that no Keys are defined for my tables, and cannot understand why.

I have the following Classes :-

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleID;

    //[Display(Name = "Title")]
    //[MaxLength(255)]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage="Title is required")]
    public string ArticleTitle;

    //[Display(Name = "Date")]
    //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, NullDisplayText = "")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
    public DateTime ArticleDate;

    //[Display(Name = "Text")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Text is required")]
    public string ArticleText;

    //[Display(Name = "Source")]
    public string ArticleSource;

    //[Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID;

    [Display(Name = "Category Title")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Title is required")]
    public string CategoryTitle;

}

public class CommonsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        //A one-to-one relationship between the Article and Category tables. 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasRequired(x => x.Category);
    }

}
```

and in the web.config :-

```
<add name="CommonsContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Personal.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

When I browse to the App_Data folder, I cannot even see the Personal.sdf, so it means that its not even created.

What am I doing wrong?  Can't figure out as yet.

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because you haven't defined getters and setters for your key properties

```
public int ArticleID { get; set; }

public int CategoryID { get; set; }
```

Comment: oh yeah your're right archil!  Had it infront of me :(  Thanks a lot for pointing that out!